# Symfony2 custom Password Encoder (bcrypt)

Tags: symfony, bcrypt

I've written my own password encoder which implements the `PasswordEncoderInterface`:

```
class BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface {
    protected $encoder;

    public function __construct(BCryptEncoder $encoder) {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
        return $this->encoder->encodeString($raw, $salt);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) {
        return $this->encoder->encodeString($raw, $salt) == $encoded;
    }
}
```

The encoder is registered as a service with the id `bcrypt.password.encoder`. But I don't know, how to tell symfony to user it.
Currently the `app/config/security.yml` looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        neo4j:
          id: security.user.provider.neo4j
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            provider: neo4j
            pattern:    ^/.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Btw I'm not using any doctrine entities.

**Edit**: `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User` is my UserObject. I modified the `security.yml` a bit:

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 
        id: bcrypt.password.encoder
```

which results in a fatal error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to EMC3\Bundle\UserBundle\Neo4jUserProvider::__construct() must be an instance of EMC3\Bundle\UserBundle\UserManager, instance of EMC3\Bundle\UserBundle\BCryptEncoder given, called in /var/www/emc3/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 227 and defined in /var/www/emc3/src/EMC3/Bundle/UserBundle/Neo4jUserProvider.php line 29
```

Which doesn't make any sense for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of November 2011, before Symfony 2.2, this is not directly supported.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest you to use the [Blowfish Password Encoder bundle I wrote (`ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle`)](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle), which solves the same problem. Or, at least, you can see how it's implemented.

If you're using Symfony 2.2 or later, [see Seldaek's answer for configuration instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213609/symfony2-custom-password-encoder-bcrypt/15165285#15165285).

Answer (score 42):

Starting from Symfony 2.2, BCrypt is [natively supported](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-bcrypt), so you can configure it easily as such:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 7
```

You may want to adjust the cost upwards if you have a fast enough server though.

Comment: And some documentation links? :)

Comment: @Jimbo added a link just for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

Your `encoders` section should look like this:

```
encoders:
    Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        id: bcrypt.password.encoder
```

where `Acme\UserBundle` is your vendor and bundle namespace, of course.

For reference, a complete example security config can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html).

**EDIT:** The way the encoder factory works (source code [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/EncoderFactory.php), relevant lines start on line 33) is that in your config, you have given the framework a class, and an encoder to use for the class. It's Doctrine-independent, so just provide the fully-qualified class name of your user object in the config instead of a "user entity," and when your password is encoded, Symfony will know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I don't have an user entity nor entities at all and that's my problem.

Comment: Gotcha. How are you managing users, then? Also, I believe if you just reference the name of your user class in the config, Symfony will recognize it.

Comment: My users are stored in a Neo4j database and I've written my own UserProvider. I'll update my original post with my full security.yml.

Comment: I tried what you described but it gives me an error (see updated question)

Comment: Can you provide a gist or similar of your UserProvider class (and the service definition for it, if relevant)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5199/discussion-between-problematic-and-prehfeldt)