# Symfony - Database driven login including a password

Tags: symfony

I'm new too Symfony 2 and need so help. I'm following this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

It helps with creating a login system and I've managed to get that working mostly. However i  the tutorial it only explain verifying using and email address or username. It has no mention of checking if the password is actually ok or how tell Doctrine which encryption algorithm to use or have to involve the salt.

If there is another article I should read that someone could point me too or if someone could explain to me how to do these thing I'd much appreciate it :)

Comment: Take a look at the symfony [security configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html), specially the section for encoders. Also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213609/symfony2-custom-password-encoder-bcrypt) about implementing a custom encoder

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I've literally read all of those articles and I think I understand them for the most part, they just don't actually give real world example. I mean who wants a login form which only requires a username :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a decent implementation of the user-mgmt is the  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle and its documentation

Used in many projects, been learning a lot when digging inside the bundle myself

Comment: can you paste your addition to config.yml here? 
According the message you posted, you're using identifier "user" instead of "fos_user" in your config.yml

Comment: Here's a good free video tutorial on FOSUserBundle. http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw